# emacs tramp ftp or ssh

Tags: emacs, tramp

I'm using emacs 23.1 on Windows XP with the following configuration

```
(require 'tramp)
(setq tramp-default-method "ftp")
```

I can open/save remote files. Find-file auto-completion with TAB works as well. But I cannot open a remote directory, it shows an empty buffer with a directory name on the top.

Here are log messages

```
ls -lhA d:/temp/ange-ftp2876pvQ
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening data connection for /bin/ls.
226 Transfer complete.
quote mdtm /soft/mysrv/jboss-4.2.3.GA/bin/
550 /soft/mysrv/jboss-4.2.3.GA/bin/: not a plain file.
quote mdtm /soft/mysrv/jboss-4.2.3.GA/bin/
550 /soft/mysrv/jboss-4.2.3.GA/bin/: not a plain file.
```

And I cannot dired-do-copy several marked files to the remote directory. It copies only the first file and says "No file on this line". Should I switch to ssh tramp to resolve these problems?

What are other advantages of changing to ssh if I don't care about security and clear text passwords?

UPDATE: I changed

```
(setq tramp-default-method "pscp")
```

and it works now.

Comment: just out of curiosity, on what kind of ftp server are you trying this?

Comment: I have a IMB AIX computer with an ftp server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it was necessary to change tramp-default-method

```
(setq tramp-default-method "pscp")
```

Now it works correctly on the servers where ssh is installed.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you how well the `ftp` method works in general as I usually work with `scp` or `ssh`. Advice like "If the ftp method doesn't work, use it" is probably not what you are looking for.

However, you may want to have a look at the `tramp-default-method-alist` variable that lets you specify which method to use based upon the remote user and the remote host.